# Query FailedYou have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update mysql database using php.

```
$connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','loginapp');
if(!$connection){
    die("database connection failed");
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$query = "UPDATE users SET ";
$query .= "username = '$username', ";
$query .= "password = '$password' ";
$query .= "WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if (!$result) {
    die("Query Failed".mysqli_error($connection));
}
}
```

I have tried every possible way of writing the following code, but everytime I am getting the error:

> Query FailedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: I have just started learning php with mysql. The topic about sql injection is yet to be covered.

Comment: You do not check that the form has been submitted anywhere in this code. Remember, when you click a link to a page the script runs... but if the form has not been submitted there will be nothing in the `$_POST` variables

Comment: @Vaishali learn it first - no point learning how to do something insecurely

Comment: Also you should not store passwords in plaintext and you should never `die` with the error message. This code example is an example of a code which no one should ever learn!

Comment: @PavanKumar I am using wamp server and all services are running

Comment: @PavanKumar I dont think you would get MySQL error messages unless MySQL was running

Comment: @treyBake I found this tutorial online and had no idea the correct way to start learning something new

Answer (score 2):

You must use prepared statements and switch on proper error reporting. Do not use `die()` to display error message. Do not store plaintext passwords in the DB, use [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead. A correct, but simple example of such code would be as follows:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$connection = new mysqli('localhost','root','','loginapp');
$connection->set_charset('utf8mb4');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $stmt = $connection->prepare('UPDATE users SET username=?, password=? WHERE id=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['username'], $password, $_POST['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```